# Get select2 selected items using data to prevent sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I've doing some research about a problem I'm having with jQuery select2 plugin. The select2 sorts the selected items (no matter which order you choose them) when posting form. I know it may not be a select2 specific bug, but standard html select behaviour.

Now, how could I get the selected items IDs and then put them in a comma separated list in a hidden input so I can respect the order the items were chosen?

```
$("#formpacint").submit(function (event) {  
    var data = $('#campoprofesionales').select2('data');  
    $('#hidprofesionales').val(data);  
});
```

The above code puts the selected items (in the order they were chosen) using its data property, into the hidden input, but the console.log shows them as objects (text+id I guess)..

**I'd need to have: 35,14,29 (the ids of selected items as they were selected without sorting)**

Thanks

Comment: It is indeed standard HTML `select` behavior that you do not get option values submitted in the order they were chosen. Why exactly do you need this? I guess you would have to go with the `change` event that the plugin provides, and implement this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
var selections = (JSON.stringify($("#campoprofesionales").select2('data')));
var obj = $.parseJSON(selections);
$.each(obj, function() {                    
      console.log(this.id);
      // I here set a hidden field with the ids in the order they were selected
});
```